# Regard somebody as (being) as holy as a saint

Tags: grammar, prepositions, conjunctions

> *Regard someone as (**being**) as holy as a saint*

Is *being* here optional, and why is it so in syntactic terms?

Secondly, is it similar to the following? *It is promoted as a leisure activity, as well **as as** a social distinction.*

Comment: The difference is slight, and is answered at https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/regard-somebody-as-being-as-holy-as-a-saint.3848622/#post-19670811. -- You have parsed the sentences wrongly: 1. "They regard him [as (being)] [as holy] [as a saint]." 2. " It is promoted [as a leisure activity], [as well as] [as a social distinction]. The third "as" in 2. is rarely used. "As" may be a preposition or an adverb.